# The periodic part of a locally nilpotent group.

Tags: group-theory, nilpotent-groups

Let $G$ be a locally nilpotent group and let $T$ be the periodic subgroup of $G$ (*i.e.*, the locally nilpotent groups have a torsion subgroup). Then $T= \prod T_p$, where $T_p=\langle \{x \in T | \exists n \in \mathbb{N}^* :|x|=p^n\}\rangle$ and $p$ is a prime.

My question is this:

> Could we write the $T_p$ without $\langle \rangle$? I mean like this:
>   $T_p =\{x \in T | \exists n \in \mathbb{N}^* :|x|=p^n\}$.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes because local nilpotency implies that the product of two elements of order a power of $p$ also has order a power of $p$.

Comment: is that mean that $\{x \in T | \exists n \in \mathbb{N}^* :|x|=p^n\}$ are also subgroups?

Answer (score 1):

In order to close the question, here is @DerekHolt's comment answering the question.

> Yes because local nilpotency implies that the product of two elements of order a power of $p$ also has order a power of $p$.